# play audio file in the background

Tags: python, audio, pydub

I want to play an audio file in the background (without blocking the rest of my code) using Pydub library.
Here is the code I have so far but it will wait till the audio finishes and then run the remaining of the code

```
sound = AudioSegment.from_wav('myfile.wav')
play(sound)
print("I like this line to be executed simoultinously with the audio playing")
```

Comment: suggest you read about python threads

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Play your sound in a new thread:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play
import threading

sound = AudioSegment.from_wav('myfile.wav')
t = threading.Thread(target=play, args=(sound,))
t.start()

print("I like this line to be executed simoultinously with the audio playing")
```